# FactoryBot - create nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm learning how to test in rails and I'm writing a factory for my question model:

```
require 'factory_bot'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :question do
    sequence(:content) { |n| "question#{n}" }
    source "BBC"
    year "1999"
  end
end
```

The problem is that I have a `has_many :choices` relationship, where I should have 5 choices for my question. So I would like to know how to do that on factory bot. Don't got it from the documentation so would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is my question model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :question_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :choices

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, limit: 5

  validates :content, :source, :year, presence: true
  validate :check_number_of_choices,


  def check_number_of_choices
    if self.choices.size != 5
        self.errors.add :choices, I18n.t("errors.messages.number_of_choices")
    end
  end

end
```

My choice model:

```
class Choice < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :question

  validates :content, presence: true, allow_blank: false


end
```

My factory code:

```
FactoryBot.define do

    factory :question_status do
        name "Pending"
    end

  factory :choice do
    sequence(:content) { |n| "choice #{n}" }
    question
  end


  factory :question do
    sequence(:content) { |n| "question #{n}" }
    source "BBC"
    year "1999"
    user
    question_status

        before :create do |question|
        create_list :choice, 5, question: question
    end

  end

end
```

And my feature test (it still does nothing, but it already fails just to create the questions because of my validation):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Evaluating Questions" do

    before do
        puts "before"
        @john = FactoryBot.create(:user)
        login_as(@john, :scope => :user)
        @questions = FactoryBot.create_list(:question, 5)
        visit questions_path
    end


    scenario "A user evaluates a question correctly" do
        puts "scenario"
    end


end
```

Comment: I think you're running in a "circular dependency", as you're validating your question should have assigned at least 5 choices, so they should be created before the question and then assigned to it, but you can't create a choice without a question. Can you tell us if this is right?

Comment: kinda yeah, but I don't have any trouble to create it from my form for the question and choices as nested attributes

Comment: Quite interesting. The truth is I don't know how to replicate your current workflow to create factories. If you wanna add more info I'd be glad to give it another try.

Comment: actually I removed that validation. Since the choice content is validated and in my controller I created 5 of them for the form, It will be validated the way I want anyway

Comment: you helped me a lot, if you post a answer explaining it, I will be glad to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's possibly going on here is the use of `select` with the `choices` collection proxy is causing Rails to attempt to load the collection from the DB again during the validation but they haven't been persisted yet.  Try removing the `select` from your validation

```
if self.choices.size != 5
```

The `select` probably isn't really needed anyway since the `Choice` model already verifies that content has to be present.  You'll probably also need to assign the choices to the question when you build the list

```
before :create do |question|
  question.choices = build_list :choice, 5, question: question
end
```

Comment: I removed the select but it still gives me the validation error

Comment: @RonanLopes Oh - you probably also need to assign the choices when you build them - Added to the answer