# How to create FactoryBot factory for model that has validation on minimum amount of associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a User model that is only valid when there is at least one Address:

```
class User
  has_many :addresses
  validates :addresses, length: { miniumum: 1}
end

class Address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I tried defining my FactoryBot factory like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    association :address
    name 'test'
  end
end
```

When creating a user with `create(:user)`, there's an error that user could not be saved due to missing address. It seems the association is only created after the user is created (which obviously creates a validation error). What's the correct way to build my factory?

Thanks

Comment: How does it work in real life? I mean - how can I set a user_id for an address without creating a user?

Comment: By saving the user and a minimum of 1 address through a nested form, in which user accepts nested attributes for the address. This part is already working, just wanted to write tests for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FactoryBot - create nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351809/factorybot-create-nested-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'test'

    before(:create) do |user|
      user.addresses << build(:address, user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

Please remember to create a factory for `address` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`association` attribute, should only be used if the model contains the foreign key (the model which you declared `belongs_to` on it). Remove `association :address` from your factory and use `before(:create)` callback to build addresses before saving user:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    name 'test'
    before(:create) { |object| object.addresses.build() }
  end
end
```

Comment: This will still not let me create(:user) without a validation error (you must provide an address)

Comment: You also must correct the spelling error in the word minimum in your validates clause.

Comment: @SajadRastegar I have checked your solution but it is not working. That's why I decided to post a little bit different answer that works for me.